# setTimeout in mounted hook doesn't work if delay is greater than 57000ms (57sec)

Tags: vue.js, settimeout, delay

I try to logout a user after 10min, so I do the following in my Member.vue (layout) page:

```
<scrip>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  data: () => ({}),

  methods: {
    ...mapActions("authentication", ["logout"]),
  },

  mounted() {
    setTimeout(this.logout, 60*1000*10);
  },
};
</script>
```

but the `logout` function is not executed after 10 min.
If I put a delay greater than 57000 (57sec) the function is never executed.

Comment: This is probably not the best approach, a middleware with a cookie with an expiration timestamp should be better. Still, you tried to stay on this component without touching to anything and the `logout` works for 56s but not for 58?

Comment: Yes, without touching anything on the same component it works for 56s but not 58s.

Comment: Super strange... Are you sure you don't have anything else loaded on your page? Did you do a refresh while testing to remove the past watchers?

Comment: @Cart Can you share a link to a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Ok guys, I was calling the function in the wrong place.
The goal is to disconnect a user after 10min, so I put the "setTimeout()" in my login function (after success) and now everything is fine.
Thanks everyone.